# Oracle between query on string field

Tags: sql, oracle

I having a table like this

```
---------------------------
|id |condition_values     |
---------------------------
|1  |2012-05-12           |
|2  |2012-06-12           |
|3  |2012-07-12           |
|4  |2012-08-12           |
---------------------------
```

So when I trying to query like

```
select * from tableName where condition_values >= TO_DATE('2012-05-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND condition_values <= TO_DATE('2012-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

I getting SQL Error

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Note: `value` is a `VARCHAR2` field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from tableName where "value" >= TO_DATE('2012-05-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND "value" <= TO_DATE('2012-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd');
--                             ^^^^^
```

You have an [implicit type conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#sthref328) here using you NLS date format, as, according to the documentation (same link):

> When comparing a character value with a DATE value, Oracle converts the character data to DATE.

---

The quick fix is to write:

```
select * from tableName where TO_DATE("value", 'yyyy-mm-dd') >= TO_DATE('2012-05-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
                           AND TO_DATE("value", 'yyyy-mm-dd') <= TO_DATE('2012-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

But, as your date format is lexicography comparable, you *might* write that instead:

```
select * from tableName where "value" >= '2012-05-12' 
                           AND "value" <= '2012-07-12';
```

*However*, I would strongly suggest you to fix your data to ensure that you use the proper `DATE` type for your column. This will avoid a bunch of possible bugs and problems like this one.

As suggested by *Falco* in a comment below, *"if you cannot change the column type to `DATE`, you should probably create a function-based Index for the `TO_DATE(...)` Value to get fast query times"*.

Comment: If you cannot change the column type to date, you should probably create a function-based Index for the TO_DATE(...) Value to get fast query times! - you could then use the index with a view - so no extra coding is required. But saving the initial data as DATE would be the best option

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Falco ! I took the liberty to add that to my answer. Please fell free to revert if you desagree.

Comment: @Falco Sometimes in the same column normal string values would also come

Comment: @Suganthan Then you should create a function based index which returns NULL for ROWs which do not contain a valid date. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966274/how-to-handle-to-date-exceptions-in-a-select-statment-to-ignore-those-rows

Answer (score 1):

<s>`VALUE` is a reserved word. Either change the column name or:</s>

```
select * from tableName 
where `value` >= TO_DATE('2012-05-12', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND value <= TO_DATE('2012-07-12','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Reference: [Reserved Words in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm)

If I were you, I will avoid using reserved words in column names.

---

OP has updated the question. It is recommended to use `DATE` column type instead of `VARCHAR2` to avoid `TO_DATE()` conversion. Faster querying, Less problem.

Comment: Sorry. the column name is not `value` that is just a test column name. I 'll update my question