# How to handle date error within a single SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, error-handling

I want to be able to run a query like this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(date_id, 'YYYYMMDD') FROM dates;
```

Most of the data is fine, for example date_id would be 20240118 for Jan 18 2024, but there are some errors in this table where a date_id will be something like 202401**53** where the date is invalid, and the query will throw an error (day of month must be between 1 and last day of month).

Is it possible to just return NULL when it hits an out of range value so that the query can finish running?

Just changing the data in the table would work but I want to run a query on a table where 99% of the data works and there's just a few invalid rows. Just getting the rows that return an error would also be a helpful solution.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: If your version of Oracle supports it, `to_date(date_id default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd')` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear, but this looks like Postgresql, so that's how I'll build my answer.

> Just getting the rows that return an error would also be a helpful solution.

Indeed. Finding this information, and correcting both the bad data and the application that allowed the bad data to be entered, so you can run the actual query cleanly, is almost certainly the better option. Bonus points for fixing this schema design (I say "fix", because it really is **broken** as it is) to use a date type in the first place.

You can use this answer to construct the query to get the bad rows:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/5966390/3043

Answer (score 1):

Adding comment as answer. If your version of Oracle supports it (appears to be oracle based on your error message), then the *default null on conversion error* clause would be nice here.

```
to_date(date_id default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Non-dates would be displayed as null.

```
with my_data as (
  select '20240118' as date_id union all
  select '20242310' as date_id union all
  select '20240153' as date_id
  )
select 
 date_id, 
 to_date(date_id default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd') as date2
from my_data
```

| DATE_ID | DATE2 |
| --- | --- |
| 20240118 | 18-JAN-24 |
| 20242310 | *null* |
| 20240153 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GTKtXlhY)

Then you could also select from the query to get only the rows which are null.